# How to extract a string to get latitude, longitude

Tags: regex

Here is my regex

```
^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$
```

I can't extract lat, longitude if my string is like this

> My location is 3.156831, 101.711125. Or you can directly Search
>   "KLCC".

I tried to extract lat, longitude or lat,longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex should be - `(\d+\.\d+)`

[For Demo - Click here !!!](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B)&i=My%20location%20is%203.156831%2C%20101.711125.%20Or%20you%20can%20directly%20Search%20%22KLCC%22.)

Comment: sorry.. i using c#

Comment: sorry.. i not down vote. thank for your answer. its work.

Comment: `string regexPattern = "(\\d+\\.\\d+)";
            string Content = "My location is 3.156831, 101.711125. Or you can directly Search \"KLCC\".";
            MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(Content, regexPattern);
            var list = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();`

Comment: Yes. It will return list or array of match elements.